# Deletion in a regex

Tags: java, regex, talend

I will split up this problem to be more easy to me :

for this expression :

```
"created":"589c8377576a33706397f3f4"
```

I write this regex :

```
output_row.json.replaceAll("\"created\":\"589c8377576a33706397f3f4\"","");
```

It works ! Now I would like to use a dynamic token e.g. `[[:xdigit:]]`.

I try this but It didn't work !

```
output_row.json.replaceAll("\"created\":\"[[:xdigit:]]\"","");
```

Could you advice me, please ?

Comment: #1, where does `"589c8377576a33706397f3f4"` come from. You will have to at least show `output_row`. #2 what *exactly* does "This part can be variable" mean? How variable? What are the restrictions. If you can answer that, you can probably write a regex for it.

Comment: They aren't of much use if you don't edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Do not  use regex to modify JSON, parse it with the appropriate tool.

Comment: This is really hard to tell without more information. Please [edit] your question and add a picture of the job layout, the underlying data and an explanation where this 589... hash comes from.

Comment: Hi OK, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer :

```
//replace the value of the key created 
output_row.json = output_row.json.replaceAll("\"created\":\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\"","\"created\":\"" + formatted + "\"");
```

I don't know why this class is not accepted in Talend editor : `[[:xdigit:]]`not specific to Java perhaps ?

Anyway the topic is closed for me !

Ale

Answer (score 2):

`[[:xdigit:]]` is exactly one hex digit. Add the `+` quantifier to match 1 to n, or the `*` to match 0 to n hex digits.

Comment: Hi, I try with `output_row.json = output_row.json.replaceAll("\"created\":\"[[:xdigit:]]+\"","");` but I didn't succeed under talend ( I try with * too). But when I type this : [`(\"created\"\:\")+([[:xdigit:]]+)\"`](https://regex101.com/r/eF8MLb/1). Could you help me please ?